# Only give focus to IconButton in TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `TextFormField` for password entry with an `IconButton` which toggles `obscureText`. I want to make it such that when the button is clicked, the text field does not come into focus. However, that is not the case. I suppose this has something to do with `FocusNode`.

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
  valueListenable: _obscureText,
  builder: (context, obscureText, child) => TextFormField(
    obscureText: obscureText,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      suffixIcon: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(obscureText ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility),
        onPressed: () => _obscureText.value = !obscureText,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Does anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
FocusNode.unfocus()
```

Call it after `setState` in your `onPressed()` method.

**Output:**

[image]

Full solution:

```
bool obscureText = false;
FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            obscureText: obscureText,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(obscureText ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() => obscureText = !obscureText);
                  Timer.run(() => _focusNode.unfocus());
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TextField(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the touch ripple on the text field when pressing the button?